# What are good .NET spell checking libraries for console apps?

Tags: c#, .net, spell-checking

I realize a very similar question was asked on SO in the past, but that was a while ago, and some of the replies no longer work.

The first road I went down was the .NET port of Aspell.  Problems I ran into were:
1.  The website is worthless.  Cannot browse source, no binaries available, broken links...
2.  Trying to build Aspell on Windows 7, then create my own .NET wrapper was turning into a complete hack involving installing MinGW, then MinGW/SYS, then Cygwin.  Every time I would follow the directions on how to build ASpell for Win, but never worked.

This is going to be for very large amounts of data, sending it to a web service like google or whatever is most likely out of the question.

I'm going to try NHunspell next, unless there other suggestions out there.

I'm currently using RapidSpell for ASP.NET spell checking, but am not sure how it compares to some others.

thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

[Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) is port of Java Lucene.  I played with it enough to discover it worked reasonably well before finding that it was much faster to just let SQL 2005 handle misspelled data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [The NetSpell project](http://www.loresoft.com/projects/netspell/the-netspell-project/default.aspx)?